# Jackson Unmarshalling not-provided values

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, jackson

I'm currently trying to implement a PATCH endpoint that should only change values that are actually provided in the JSON Post Body. Unfortunately, it looks like Jackson is treating non-provided values as NULL though, thus resetting those existing values.
Following example:

```
public class Item {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    //getters+setters
}
```

and the according Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = /item/{id}, method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
public ResponseEntity<Item> patchItem(@PathVariable("id") Long itemId, @RequestBody Item item) {
    if (itemRepository.exists(itemId) && item.getId().equals(itemId)) {
        Item newItem = itemRepository.save(item);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newItem, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    throw new ResourceNotFoundException("could not find Item with id " + itemId);
}
```

When I call to that endpoint now with just the ID provided, I want the existing name NOT to be nulled:

```
PATCH to /item/1 with postbody { "id":1 }
```

should result in

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"value_before_patch"
}
```

and not in `{ "id":1 }` (name not provided because of `builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);)` as it is now.

How do I need to configure Jackson to achieve that?

Comment: Did you check whether the name is present in Item method parameter in your controller?

Comment: You mean doing the checks manually? Eg, loading the existing entity first from the database, and then check if the supplied entity has the value set and if it's there and different, then update the values? 
How would I then NULL a value (eg, if I want to unlink a connection)?
And wouldn't that be more or less the same as doing a PUT with the whole object?

Comment: What I mean is to narrow down the problem between JSON conversion and data repository? Which component is eating up the value of "name" parameter?

Comment: the name is not part of the method parameter - in my example it's only id. 

that's the whole idea of the PATCH method: you only supply the fields that you actually want changed (in that case my example is a bit sloppy as I don't want the id to change, but for the sake of simplicity...).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's something I don't understand in the question, but :
if you provide an incomplete object representation in JSON, the resulting fields in java will be null. How could it be different from that? When you save the (incomplete) deserialized object, the fields that weren't specified in JSON will be nullified. You can't do anything about that.
What you could do is check each and every field on the java object you're about to save, and put the old value in every null field.

As a side note, this is the reason (afaict) PATCH is not a common service, i.e. it is quite hard to implement particularly if you have complex objects.

Edit :
I didn't knew about the `json-patch` proposed standard. This could be a solution to what you are trying to achieve. I'd suggest you take a look at [this tutorial on how to integrate it with Jersey](http://kingsfleet.blogspot.be/2014/02/transparent-patch-support-in-jax-rs-20.html), or even at the [rfc (6902)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902). In a nutshell, json-patch formalizes how you can send commands (*patches*) to selectively modify an object. An example is the following :

given an object whose json initial representation is

```
{  
  "list" : [  
    "one",  
    "two"  
  ],  
  "message" : "message",  
  "title" : "title"  
}
```

You can patch it with a json like

```
[  
  {  
    "op" : "replace",  
    "path" : "/message",  
    "value" : "otherMessage"  
  },  
  {  
    "op" : "add",  
    "path" : "/list/-",  
    "value" : "three"  
  }  
]
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: How would I then unset a value that I want explicitly nulled? (And wouldn't that be more or less the same as doing a PUT with the whole object?)

Comment: In theory you can't, i.e. you have no way to distinguish whether the null you're receiving is a non-updated field or a nullified one. That's another reason why the update operation is commonly implemented with PUT rather than PATCH. If you want to use PATCH, a workaround that comes to mind is to define a convention for declaring null objects, (e.g. a null String would be `"null"`). This way you can distinguish the two cases, but it has a lot of downsides.

Comment: @francesco foresti i.e: booleans